# Getting console output in python string

Tags: python, linux

I have a problem with getting some linux code output in python.
I think it is because of escape characters

The command I trying to run

```
nmap 192.168.1.* -p T:80 --open | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub (/\(|\)/,""); up = $NF}'
```

and i wanna replace that 192.168.1.*  with a string variable like

```
network = "192.168.1.*"
nmap + network + -p T:80 --open | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub (/\(|\)/,""); up = $NF}'
```

Every time i try getting error. 
Thanks for response!

Comment: And how is Python getting involved? What error do you get and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution like this

```
command = "nmap "+network+ " -p T:80 --open | awk " + r"""'/is up/ {print up}; {gsub (/\(|\)/,""); up = $NF}'"""
output = str(os.popen(command).read()).strip()
print output
```

thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting your question as a bash related question

Using a string variable works like this:

```
$ export network="192.168.1.*"
$ nmap $network -p T:80 --open | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub (/\(|\)/,""); up = $NF}'
```

I didn't check the rest of the command, though...